# checking for diagonals on N-queens

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

• `diagonal_conflict(board, r,  c)`:

Given a board and two integers indicating row/column positions,
determine if a queen is already placed at the same diagonal as coordinate (r,c); return the answer as a
boolean.

examples

> o diagonal_conflict([[True,False],[False,False]],1,1) → True
>
> o diagonal_conflict([[True,False],[False,False]],1,0) → False

I;ve figured out these 3 things

> 1. Subtract 1 from both r and c, until you go out of bounds which is when r or c hits negative
> 2. Add 1 to both r and c, until you go out of bounds. which is len(board)
> 3. Add 1 to r, subtract 1 from c (this is to get the diagonal going the other way)

But have no idea on how to start writing the code for it. I know I need 3 loops for each of those above.
The best I have is

```
def conflict(board,r,c):
      for (r,c) in board
          if r+1==r and...
```

Pretty sure this is wrong tho, can anyone put my ideas into python code?

Comment: You have all the right ideas. Some say if you can speak English you can write Python. To give you a hint, what if you rewrote every sentence in your question that uses the word "until" so that it uses the word "while"?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.  I made it just for you ;)

```
def diagonal_conflict(board, r, c):
    for r_add, c_add in ((-1, -1), (1, 1), (-1, 1), (1, -1)):
        current_r = r
        current_c = c
        while 0 <= current_r < len(board) and 0 <= current_c < len(board[0]):
            if board[current_r][current_c]:
                return True
            current_r += r_add
            current_c += c_add
     return False
```

Another solution whose logic was created by @abhaybhatia is now converted to Python:

```
def diagonal_conflict(board, r, c):
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board[i])):
            if board[i][j] and (float(c-j)/(r-i) in (1, -1)):
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: Thanks! but the definition must use exactly board,r,c for the tests to pass... any fix?

Comment: @Jessica: I have modified it and added abhaybhatia's solution.

Comment: @Jessica - if zondo's answer solved your problem you should probably accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

You have all the right ideas. Some say if you can speak English you can write Python. To give you a hint, what if you rewrote every sentence in your question that uses the word *until* so that it uses the word *while* instead?

For example,

> Subtract 1 from both r and c, until you go out of bounds which is when r or c hits negative

Can be rewritten as

> While r and c aren't negative, subtract 1 from r and subtract 1 from c

The Python then becomes obvious:

```
while r >= 0 and c >= 0:
    # check for a queen
    r -= 1
    c -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have the queen in 4 directions

1. r and c decreasing
2. r decreasing c increasing
3. r increasing c decreasing
4. r and c increasing

So if you know the position of the queens, you should check if the slope of the r,c and queen coordinates is 1 or -1 - then they are on the same diagonal

here is some python code

```
def diagonal_conflict(board, r, c):
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board[i])):
            if board[i][j] and (float(c-j)/(r-i) in (1, -1)):
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but wasn't this question tagged `python`?  A newbie isn't likely to be very good at code translation.

Comment: good point, maybe i'll write pseudo code instead

Comment: I think pseudo code is what he already has, in a way.

Comment: yep I know what I want but I'm stuck on how to structure it in python to pass my tests.

Comment: def diagonal_conflict(board, r, c):
   while not (r<0 or c<0):
      r-=1
      c-=1
 while not (r>len(board)):
      r+=1
      c+=1

Comment: don't know why ctrl+k isnt working here, works in chat room

Comment: @Jessica: You can put `\`` around the code to make it show up nicely.  The comments here can't have new lines, but at least you can give it a grey background.  My apologies for referring to you as "he".  I hadn't noticed what your username was.

Comment: @zondo no problem, it's fine haha. And could someone experienced just give me the code answer here? I came up with the pseudo code and stressed for time at this point... Would really appreciate a straight out answer in coding...

Comment: I have java code, still working hard to convert it to python. Perhaps Zondo can help with that

Comment: This code runs over all the squares in the board and if that square has a true in it .. then it checks the slope of that square against r,c .. if the slope is 1 or -1, it returns true ... after going through all the squares in the board it returns false (if haven't returned true already)

Comment: ` public boolean checkQueen(boolean[][] board, int r, int c) {
  for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
    if (board[i][j]) {
     int slope = (c - j) / (r - i);
     if (slope == 1 || slope == -1) {
      return true;
     }
    }
   }
  }
  return false;
 }`

Comment: @abhaybhatia: I have added your solution to my answer...converted to Python.

Comment: updated the answer with python code

Comment: Your code isn't quite valid.  Python doesn't use the `.length` attribute.  To get the length of a list, you should use `len(...)`  Also, you should use `for` loops instead of `while`; it makes the code shorter.  In fact, if you just copied the code from my answer, you'd have a good function ;)

Comment: Thanks ... I used an online convertor to get python code ... I'll copy from yours now :D